# Are the US presidential debates pre-taped?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, media, debate

Just before the beginning of the third presidential debate, the moderator reminded the audience they needed to keep quiet during the event, and said they would be starting things momentarily "at 3:00."  This is three hours before the nominal broadcast time.  Was the event pre-recorded and strictly embargoed, or was the moderator just wrong about the start time of the event he was moderating?

Comment: I noticed that, and assumed it was a slip of the tongue, or applying the NYC-to-Las Vegas shift (-3 hours) twice.  Reasonable question, though.

Answer (score 1):

I watched all 3 debates and if I remember correctly, they all started at 9PM Eastern time. The following quote comes from the [Commission on Presidential Debates](http://www.debates.org/index.php?page=2016debates), which is the organization responsible of organizing the debates:

> All debates will be moderated by a single individual and will run from 9:00-10:30 p.m. Eastern Time without commercial breaks.

Comment: What about Martha Raddatz and Anderson Cooper pair in the second debate?

Comment: @Max I don't know if it was a mistake or not, but that is another question.

Comment: Those were the air times. At what times did the debates actually occur?